# How can you do a merge 'conflict report' in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, merge, beyondcompare

How can you do a merge 'conflict report' in Mercurial?

Given two conflicting revisions of a file in two heads, how can you output a report showing the parent and the two sets of revisions in each head?

Basically, I would like to send a 'report' of the conficts to the developer who owns the file so he can comment on how best to do the merge.

We use BeyondCompare as our merge tool - couldn't see an option to do this in BeyondCompare.

Answer (score 0):

Revisions span all files, so whatever report you're envisioning it won't have revision info per-file.

If you've begun a merge with `hg merge` and have gotten merge conflicts you can do `hg resolve --list` to get a list of all the files that conflict.  The `hg parents` command will, during a merge, list the two heads that are being merged.

You could use something like `hg archive -I file1 -I file2 --revision head1 head1.zip` to make an archive file with the files file1 and file2 as they stood at revision head1.  If you do that for all the files in conflict and for each head you've got something you can send.

Ideally you just tell the dev to pull, merge, and push the merge -- this is easily handled within Mercurial and clumsily handled outside of it.